# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.core.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.xml.XMLObjectBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, opensaml, spring-security-saml2

In our application, we are trying to upgrade to Spring boot 2,
We are using  *spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.4.RELEASE*, while running application we are getting following exception.  It seems,  there are two jars *xmltooling-1.4.6* and *opensaml-core-3.3.0* on classpaath, who have same file `default-config.xml`. In this case  a classloader happens to put *opensaml-core-3.3.0*  ahead of *xmltooling-1.4.6.jar* and wrong `default-config.xml` getting loaded

```
<ObjectProviders>
        <ObjectProvider qualifiedName="xt:DEFAULT">
        <BuilderClass className="org.opensaml.core.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyBuilder"/>
        <MarshallingClass className="org.opensaml.core.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyMarshaller"/>
        <UnmarshallingClass className="org.opensaml.core.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyUnmarshaller"/>
    </ObjectProvider>  </ObjectProviders> 

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.core.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.xml.XMLObjectBuilder
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.initializeObjectProviders(XMLConfigurator.java:236)
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:182)
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:166)
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:143)
        at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:203)
        at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:186)
        at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultBootstrap.java:92)
        at org.opensaml.PaosBootstrap.bootstrap(PaosBootstrap.java:27)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap.postProcessBeanFactory(SAMLBootstrap.java:42).
```

Can somebody help here. Please..

Comment: This [topic](http://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/Opensaml-Classpath-issues-td7638136.html), perhaps, might be helpful?

Answer (score 6):

Refer https://issues.shibboleth.net/jira/browse/OSJ-152

`opensaml` V2 version uses `xmltooling.jar`.

`opensaml` V3 version uses `opensaml-soap-impl.jar` which has different package name compared to `xmltooling.jar`

**Example:**

- `opensaml-soap-impl.jar`  uses -->  `org.opensaml.core.xml.XMLObjectBuilder`
- `xmltooling.jar` uses -->  `org.opensaml.xml.XMLObjectBuilder`

Root causue: your classpath has both v2 and v3 versions of `opensaml`. This is reason for `classcast` exception.

**Solution:**

Ideally you don't need to have both versions of `opensaml`. it might happen accidentally due to maven dependency management. Remove one of them.

1. If your code base compatible with `opensamlv2` version and if you don't want to upgrade, please exclude `opesamlv3` jars as below.
2. Otherwise upgrade your codebase to compatible with v3 version and remove `opensamlV2` related jars