# spring-security-saml2-core upgrade with sprig boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-saml2

We are trying to upgrade our app to spring boot 2.0 and while doing that we got error [java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.core.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.xml.XMLObjectBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557754/java-lang-classcastexception-org-opensaml-core-xml-schema-impl-xsanybuilder-can). After lot of research, we found that, we are running into trouble because we have two opensaml jars in classpath ( 2 and 3) and decided to upgrade  to upgrade spring-security-saml2-core jar to 2.0.0.

We downloaded 2.0.0.SNAPHSHOT jar but it seems there are lot of classes changed/renamed. Is there any documentation/examples where i can compare and migrate my old code easily. For e.g.  old jar SamlBootStrap class and new one dont have.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The differences between the two versions are dramatic, and I understand that also the differences between the opensaml library versions are pretty much so. I made a little project for myself to learn how to use this new versions, and maybe can help you too.
[Samlv2App](https://github.com/Endeios/samlv2app)